# What kinds of nets can be used to singlehandedly guarantee continuity?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity, order-theory, nets

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces.  Then for any directed set $A$ we can define nets in $X$ and $Y$ indexed by $A$.  And a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at a point $x$ if and only if all $f$ maps all nets converging to $x$, indexed by all directed sets, to nets converging to $f(x)$.

But something stronger than that is true.  Let $A_0$ is the set of all open sets containing $x$, endowed with a partial order $\leq$ defined by saying that $U\leq V$ if $V$ is a subset of $U$.  Then $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $f$ maps all nets converging to $x$ indexed by $A_0$ to nets in $Y$ converging to $f(x)$.  What that means is that if $f$ maps all nets converging to $x$ indexed by $A_0$ to nets converging to $f(x)$, then $f$ maps all nets converging to $x$ indexed by all directed sets to nets in converging to $f(x)$.

My question is, are there any directed sets other than $A_0$ which have this property?  The natural numbers under the standard ordering clearly do not have this property, unless the topological space is well-behaved, since a function $f$ mapping sequences converging to $x$ to sequences converging to $f(x)$ can fail to be continuous at $x$.  What about the real numbers, or the ordinal numbers?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: It turns out you can do quite a lot with transfinite sequences (nets with an ordinal as the domain) instead of just arbitary nets. See [this paper by Howes](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm106/fm106120.pdf) e.g.